# Free Delivery and Coupon Codes

Tags: magento2, discount, coupon-codes, free-shipping, delivery

A client has a site that offers free shipping over £20 as a delivery method. 
However, there are also some discount codes 15% off etc.

The client has a major issue with peoples baskets being £20+ then using a discount code and still qualifying for free delivery.

Is there a way of setting up the free delivery method to only apply to the basket after any coupons are used?

I also thought I could create a free delivery coupon and automatically apply it to the basket and set the priority after any other coupon, but can't seem to figure the rules out, other than giving a flat discount of the delivery cost on basket total.

[image]